# How to save converted images by automator to the same folder?

Tags: image, macos, save, action, automator

I use an Automator service to convert images to pdf documents. Unfortunately, this workflow can only save the converted files to a specific folder instead of converting images then saving the results in the same folder

[An image of the workflow that I'm currently using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PiRV.png)

Comment: Please provide more details on the problem and what you have tried. This is too broad. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: @sparkplug I've found the answer that I need in this website https://macinjune.com/mac/tip/맥-여러장의-사진-pdf-파일로-합치기-automator/ This method works.

Comment: The last method didn't work properly. It can save the pdf document to the original folder but converts only one photo instead of multiple photos and the workflow shows an error (The action "New PDF from Images" encountered an error: "*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter").

Comment: Here's an image of the log https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP0W9.png

Comment: This error happens when I create the service myself but when I download it from MacinJune website it works.